# Converting colors in a bitmap android

Tags: android

I have a simple image in my project for android 2.3.3 that i want to know the color of the first pixel and replace every pixel  with that color to the background color.... I tried everything like iterating the pixels and setting the color of the pixels and I get nothing...For example,with that picture:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9dcq72c9u5o3op/img2.jpg

I want to get a result like that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9zox7zueekq2xe/img3.jpg

I'm a very new developer for Android, and because of that sorry for my NAIF question!

Answer (score 4):

Simply use ColorFilter to achieve this. It will replace one colour with another. Working example:

```
    Paint pnt = new Paint();
    Bitmap myBit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBit );

    int myColor = myBit.getPixel(0, 0);

    // Set the colour to replace.
    ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(myColor, Color.WHITE );
    pnt.setColorFilter(filter);

    // Draw onto new bitmap. result Bitmap is newBit
    myCanvas.drawBitmap(myBit,0,0, pnt);
```

Comment: Instead of creating a copy bitmap can I do this on the original bitmap(in your code is myBit).

Comment: @RicardoMarquesdeSousa Yea. See edit. I was just doing it for ease of read, but you are right, to save memory that is better. This will draw the new one on top of itself.

Comment: I created a subclass of ImageView, and I have a bitmap that I change among the class code and when I want to draw it on the view I call "this.setBitmapImage(myBitmap)"... I load the picture to this bitmap and the on "onDraw" i do canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap)... but applying that filter that you suggested me i get a clear bitmap with every pixel in white....

Comment: @RicardoMarquesdeSousa Hmm it works for me. although i do `new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF , myColor)` to change Black to my desire color.

Comment: can you please try using the example that I give?Thanks a lot;)

Comment: This does not work for me.  This changes the entire image to the 0,0 pixel color.

Comment: According to the documentation, LightingColorFilter doesn't do what you describe (replacing one color with another); it changes C to C*m+a for all colors C (where m and a are the arguments to the constructor). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LightingColorFilter.html